# Return an ms access column into an array

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm trying to return a column of scores from a MS Access table using java. This is the table[image]

I followed the guide from the java documentation.This is the result code

```
public class DatabaseConnector {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Connection connection=null;
        Statement statement =null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        //Loads JDBC DRIVER
        try {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfex){
            System.out.println("There was a problem loading MS Access Driver");
            cnfex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Loads Database
        try{
            String scoredb="C:/Users/User/"+"/Documents/Database2.accdb";
            String mydburl ="jdbc:ucanaccess://"+scoredb;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mydburl);
            statement = connection.createStatement();


            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT CSC103,  CSC103 FROM Scores");

            while(resultSet.next()) {
                Array z = resultSet.getArray("CSC103");
                int[] CSC103 = (int[])z.getArray();
                for (int i=0;i<CSC103.length;i++){
                    System.out.println(i);
                }

            }

        } catch (SQLException sqlex){
            sqlex.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try{
                if (null != connection) {
                    resultSet.close();
                    statement.close();
                    connection.close();
                }
            }catch (SQLException sqlex){
                sqlex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I ended up getting the error-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getArray(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getArray(UcanaccessResultSet.java:184)
    at DatabaseConnector.main(DatabaseConnector.java:28)
```

I have taken a look at this error online  and it's a bit confusing because the solutions don't apply to database. How do I fix the error and get my values  from the column?

Comment: The column contains a scalar value, not an array. You cannot get an array for this column. Result sets are **row** oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResultSet#getArray` is used with databases that support special columns in which we can store an array of values *for each row* in the table. Access does not have an `Array` column type. The `CSC103` column in your table contains a single ("scalar") value for each row, an integer in this case.

So you need to retrieve the individual values for each row and add them to a collection of some sort. The most straightforward way would be

```java
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT CSC103 FROM Scores");
java.util.List<Integer> csc103List = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    csc103List.add(rs.getInt("CSC103"));
}
```

after which you'll have the values in an `ArrayList<Integer>`. If you *really* need an `array` of type `Integer` (which is a slightly different thing) then you can convert the `List` into an `array` like so:

```java
Integer[] csc103Array = csc103List.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```